# How to Calculate Item Discount for Packet containing 3 sheet

Tags: percentages

I have some products (packets) that contain (Sheets) for example:

Product A (Unit: Packet, Packet = 5 Sheet), when I sell one packet and 2 sheet of this product, then:

Total = Packet Price + (Number of Sheet * Packet Price / 5)

But this item has discount for 30% for one Packet, I don't know how to calculate it for Sheets.

Comment: Do you want to calculate the discount on a sheet given you have a 30% discount on a packet? I guess not, but I cant figure out what your question is.

Comment: @JKnecht: Yes exactly... "Do you want to calculate the discount on a sheet given you have a 30% discount on a packet?"

Comment: So you want to know this?

Lets say you usually charge $\$y$ for a packet which consists of $5$ sheets.

With a $30\%$ discount you charge $$0.7 \cdot \$y$$.

$5 + n$ sheets is priced as $$\text{Packet Price} + (\text{Number of Sheets n} \cdot \text{Packet Price} / 5)$$

So, usually you charge $$\$y + n \cdot \$y / 5$$

Now with the discount you charge $$0.7 \cdot \$y + n \cdot 0.7 \cdot \$y / 5$$

And you want to know what discount this means per sheet?